# Trace function on the quantum expectation

Tags: linear-algebra, quantum-mechanics, quantum-computation

In the article "[Barren plateaus in quantum neural network training landscapes](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-018-07090-4.pdf)", the objective function $E(\theta)$ is defined as
$$
E(\theta) =i\langle{0|U(\theta)^\dagger H U(\theta)|0\rangle}
$$
and one has
$$
\partial_k E = i\langle0|U^\dagger_{\_}[V_k, U^\dagger_{+}HU_{+}]U_{-}|0\rangle
$$
where $U_{-} = \prod^{k-1}_{l=o}U_l(\theta_l)W_l$ and
$U_{+} = \prod^{L}_{l=k}U_l(\theta_l)W_l$ and with the assumption that
$$
p(U) = \int dU_{+}p(U_{+})\int dU_{-}p(U_{-}) \times \delta(U_{+}U_{-} - U).
$$
From the assumption,
$<\partial_k E> = \int dU p(U)\partial_k <0|U(\theta)^\dagger H U(\theta)|0>$

Here is my question. The final partial derivatives are shown as
$$
<\partial_kE> = i\int{dU_{-}p(U_{-})\,\mathrm{Tr}\{\rho_{-}\times \int{dU_{+}p(U_{+})[V, U^{\dagger}_{+}HU_{+} ]\} }}
$$
In the last expression, I want to know why Trace function appears in the last equation!

Comment: The question is still missing some context. Where does $p(U)$ come out from all of a sudden?

Comment: Oh yes it seems that $p(U)$ is the probability distribution function of $U$. Article also uses definition that $<\partial_k E> = \int dU p(U)\partial_k <0|U(\theta)^\dagger H U(\theta)|0>$. I omit this as I think it is the result of the last equation!

Comment: I include the definition in my main question!

Comment: OK, I could see the paper, but it seems that I get none the wiser out of it. I'm afraid they don't make their computation more explicit because they are leaning on some result in another paper. To me, it seems that it is the part $\langle 0| U^\dagger_- \ldots U_- |0\rangle>$ that gets transformed to a trace. They also introduce another kind of measure $\rho_-$ in the process. But it is nowhere defined.

Comment: They only say something about a unitary t-design with equation 5 and refer to papers 42-44. I think the answer might be in there.

Comment: As a high level explanation, we always have that $\langle 0| X | 0 \rangle = \text{Tr}(| 0 \rangle\langle 0| X) $. But that's not quite satisfatory enough to fill in the gaps of the derivation.

Comment: Oh my! I didn't catch it! I should check the references right now. I think that I missed the characteristics of general mathematics. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that the trace appears because they defined $\rho_- = U_{\_}|0\rangle \langle 0| \,U^\dagger_{\_}$, that is the projection on $U_{\_}|0\rangle$. Then from that and your equation on $\partial_k E$, it holds
$$
\partial_k E = i \,\mathrm{Tr}(\rho_-\,[V_k, U^\dagger_{+}HU_{+}]).
$$
Now taking the expectation with respect to the law $p$ and then using your formula for $p(U)$
$$
<\partial_k E> = i \int p(U)\,\mathrm{Tr}(\rho_-\,[V_k, U^\dagger_{+}HU_{+}])\,\mathrm  dU
\\
= i \int p(U_+)\,\mathrm{Tr}\!\left(\rho_- \int p(U_-)\,[V_k, U^\dagger_{+}HU_{+}]\,\mathrm dU_-\right) \mathrm dU_+.
$$
which is your formula, except that there is a $V_k$ instead of $V$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! with your pretty explanation, I can understand where the trace comes from! Can I ask one more minor question about your explanation? In your last expression, $\delta(\cdot)$ goes to 1?

Comment: Yes, because of the integration with respect to $U$. By definition of the Dirac delta $\int \varphi(x)\, \delta(a-x)\,\mathrm d x = \varphi(a)$, from your expression for $p(U)$, one finds that for any function $\varphi$,
$$
\int p(U) \,\varphi(U)\,\mathrm dU = \iint p(U_+) \, p(U_-) \,\varphi(U_+U_-)\,\mathrm dU_+\,\mathrm dU_-
$$
i.e. the $\delta$ is just here to ensure that $U$ is replaced by $U_+U_-$ when integrating. In your case, just replace $\varphi$ by $\partial_k E$, that is a function of $U$ already written as a function of $U_+$ and $U_-$.